# iPhone Objective C MKMapView doesn't zoom on first open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I've a little problem with my `MKMapView`.

If i open it, it should center the pin (there can be only one pin) and zoom to this pin.
That works always very good, but when I open the map for the first time, it only centers the pin but zooms out maximal.

This is my Code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.curPin != nil){
        [self.map setCenterCoordinate: self.curPin.coordinate];
    }
    else{
        [self.map setCenterCoordinate:locationManager.location.coordinate];
    }
}
```

curPin is a `CLLocation`, where i save the coordinates of my pin.

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks, Franz

Comment: please check [this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/) tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make zooming using `setRegion`

```
        MKCoordinateRegion location = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentAnnotation.coordinate, 100000.0, 100000.0);
        //MKCoordinateSpan span = {.2, .3};
        //location.span=span;

        [self.map setRegion:location animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks for that hint.
It's working very well.
not the best way but I like that too ;)
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Should you also set the Span of the map ? I hope you have done that..

```
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
span.longitudeDelta= 0.2;

MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
    mapRegion.span = span;
```

try this.. as it will set the span of your map view. I hope it helps, Cheers!! Happy Coding..

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, but there's still the same issue. :(